# how to design a database for a multiple product type for an e-commerce website in MySqL

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I am curious to know to design the architecture of a database for products with multiple options and pricing for an e-commerce web site
For example lets says.

- There are products which has only variant weights and their respective price ( For example apple, apple can be of 500g or 1kg and so the price will very )
- There are products with multiple colors and size and their price ( For example cloths they can be of different colors/ different size or both)
- There can be products which has different weight, size, colors or can have none of these.

How can i design the database so that what ever the products it is , it should be supported by the database.

For now i can design database which can hold one of them individually , but my objective to design a database which can hold all the above cases.

So far my database design is like this
[image]

This is only good , for products having multiple weights and their respective prices, but can't hold all of them.
Simillarly , i can design database where it can hold products with multiple colors and multiple size like small,xl,xxl  etc.
But i want to combine all these product types

**Objective**

Objective is to create a database for an eCommerce site like ***flipkart.com*** or ***amazon.com***, which can hold vast variety of products.

Can anyone please help me . Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Entity-Attribute-Value is a bad schema design.  You have made it worse by "over-normalizing" the product attribute names and values.

Back off on the latter, then follow the tag to other discussions of EAV.